# Seeking a site about wildlife

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Does a site about wildlife behavior exist? 
I wonder what an octopus I found in the nature historical museum shot sideways from it‘s head. It was a red string that wasn’t fluid and also sank to the bottom of the tank, although it seemed sticky. Definitely not ink.

If not, where are questions on this topic most likely acceptable?

I don‘t see [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com) as a good fit.

Comment: ehh, could we be a little more specific?

Comment: Please include the question you wish to ask on the site, which would help us find a better fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you get the idea that Biology.SE is a bad fit? There's no specific tag for wildlife, but they have a lot of questions tagged [species identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification) already.

Some questions about wildlife behaviour could be on-topic on [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/), which has some questions about [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals):

> Questions about animals likely to be encountered outdoors, whether from the perspective of food (hunting, preparing, eating), shelter (skinning), for avoidance (bears, lions, other dangerous animals), or enjoyment (bird and other animal watching, care, understanding of behavior).